# Does OpenLayers supports KML Ground Overlays?

Tags: openlayers-2, kml, overlay

I am not able to display Ground Overlays in a KML file with OpenLayers. Does OpenLayers supports KML Ground Overlays? If not, how would I proceed in writing my own code or plugin for OpenLayers so that I can display Ground Overlays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular way does not support it ([OpenLayers.Format.KML](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Format/KML-js.html#OpenLayers.Format.KML.kmlns)). as you can see this example contains an overlay in france and it does not show up in openlayers but it does in google earth.

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/sundials.html

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/kml/sundials.kml

You're going to have to parse it manually and use [OpenLayers.Layer.Image](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Image-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Image) to mount it using the bounds extrancted from the KML overlay element.