# Openlayers - how can I parse a KML file

Tags: openlayers-2, kml

I have found some info on here regarding opening a KML file (with groundoverlay) from a url in Openlayers. In order to open a KML with groundoverlay, it must first be parsed. However, after I `GET`, I am getting back a downloadable KML file. From the response in FireBug, I just see a bunch of giberish as the response! I want the KML(XML) so I can get the info out of it. Does anyone know exactly how to parse a downloadable kml from a url? Thanks!

Here is my code below. The url takes me to a kml that I can see in Google Earth. However, the response I get back is just a bunch of symbols according to Firebug, when I send as a GET. Any idea what I am doing wrong here to get the response in xml format?

```
      kmlURL='http://capstonedev/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=http%3A//10.60.26.64%3A8080/viewshed.kml%3FREQUEST%3DExecute%26DataSource%3DSRTM3%26Operation%3DLegionViewshedOperation%26Parameters%3DobserverCoord%3A-113+42%2CouterRadius%3A40000%26FORMAT%3DKML';
OpenLayers.Request.GET({
    url: kmlURL
    ,
    callback: function(request) {
        if(request.status==200)
           alert(kmlGroundOverlayParse(request.responseText));
        else
        {   alert(request.status + "::" + request.responseText);
            console.log(request.status + "::" + request.responseText);
        }
    }
})









    function kmlGroundOverlayParse(strKML)
    {
    var NL = "\r\n";
    var parserXML = new OpenLayers.Format.XML();
    try {
    objKMLxml = parserXML.read(strKML);
    } catch(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    //alert(err.message);
    return;
    }

    var Msg="";
    var objLayerList = parserXML.getElementsByTagNameNS(objKMLxml, "*", "GroundOverlay");

    for(var i=0;i<objLayerList.length;i++)
    {

    var derName = parserXML.getElementsByTagNameNS(objLayerList[i], "*", "name");

    var dasIcon = parserXML.getElementsByTagNameNS(objLayerList[i], "*", "Icon");
    var dieHREF = parserXML.getElementsByTagNameNS(dasIcon[0], "*", "href");

    var dieBox = parserXML.getElementsByTagNameNS(objLayerList[i], "*", "LatLonBox");
    var derNorden = parserXML.getElementsByTagNameNS(dieBox [0], "*", "north");
    var derWesten = parserXML.getElementsByTagNameNS(dieBox [0], "*", "west");
    var derSueden = parserXML.getElementsByTagNameNS(dieBox [0], "*", "south");
    var derOsten  = parserXML.getElementsByTagNameNS(dieBox [0], "*", "east");

    Msg += "name:" + derName[0].firstChild.nodeValue + ", ";
    Msg += "url:" + dieHREF[0].firstChild.nodeValue.substr(0,20) + ", ";
    Msg += "BOX:" + derWesten[0].firstChild.nodeValue + ", ";
    Msg += derSueden[0].firstChild.nodeValue + ", ";
    Msg += derOsten[0].firstChild.nodeValue + ", ";
    Msg += derNorden[0].firstChild.nodeValue + ", ";

    Msg += NL;

    var title = derName[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var url = dieHREF[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var projection = "EPSG:4326";

    var ptmin = [derWesten[0].firstChild.nodeValue,derSueden[0].firstChild.nodeValue];
    var ptmax = [derOsten[0].firstChild.nodeValue,derNorden[0].firstChild.nodeValue];

    var bounds = ptmin[0] + "," + ptmin[1] + "," + ptmax[0] + "," + ptmax[1];
    var size = "100,100"; //uninteressant, notwendig für addLayer??

    addKMLGroundOverlay(i, title, url, projection, bounds, size);
}

Msg += objLayerList.length;
parseMsg = Msg;
```

}

Comment: Can you show us your code? That way it'd be easier to spot errors.

Comment: GroundOverlays in Openlayers is not supported -http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16816/does-openlayers-supports-kml-ground-overlays - use LayerImage instead http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Image-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u use django or python on server side, u can use pykml(Python KML library) [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pykml).

dont forget to check out tutorials here about [pykml](http://packages.python.org/pykml/tutorial.html).

```
from lxml import etree
from pykml.parser import Schema
from pykml.factory import KML_ElementMaker as KML
from pykml.factory import GX_ElementMaker as GX
....
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: A coworker was able to make Grails specify the xml format I needed.. Guess I need to study up on server side a bit more! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried to parse a KML, just a geojson file. You may want to convert the KML to a geojson file first. Plus json files are smaller and easier to parse. I got some help [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29595/parsing-a-geojson-file-with-jquery) with looping over the geojson file. I'd use the ogr2ogr tool to convert the file